# how to configure module.config.php in zend 2

Tags: file, configuration, routes, zend-framework2

I create my new users folder in module but it has error when I use `localhost/zend/public/users/` but `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "users/users/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file`.i see some tutorials but not solved this problem. and also visit the zend's website.

my module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Users\Controller\Users' => 'Users\Controller\UsersController',
        ),
    ),
    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'users' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/users[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Users',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Well, does the `users/users/index.phtml` template exist? If so, what is the full path to it?

Answer (score 0):

The `template_path_stack` configuration parameter tells you where the framework is going to search for the templates.

According to your configuration, the `users/users/index` template should be in the `__DIR__ . '/../view/users/users/index.phtml'` file, where `__DIR__` is the directory that contains your `module.config.php` file.